# MacOS: tableView:viewForTableColumn:row: stops being called after a certain amount of rows

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa, nstableview

I have an `NSTableView` inside an `NSWindow` which is inside my xib file. The xib in Interface Builder can be view [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8JTUh.jpg). I am using a view-based table view.

My problem is that the cells' textFields in the `tableView` are only being populated up to the height of the table. From then on, `tableView:viewForTableColumn:row:` stops being called and I am left with the correct number of rows but the majority of them without text. Illustration [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8VXhr.jpg).

The `dataSource` and `delegate` methods I have implemented are below:

```
    // MARK: - Table View Data Source
    func numberOfRows(in tableView: NSTableView) -> Int {
        return builds.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: NSTableView, viewFor tableColumn: NSTableColumn?, row: Int) -> NSView? {
        guard let cellView = tableView.makeView(withIdentifier: tableColumn!.identifier, owner: nil) as? NSTableCellView else {
            return nil
        }
        let formatter = DateFormatter()
        formatter.dateFormat = "MMM d, yyyy"
        cellView.textField?.stringValue = formatter.string(from: builds[row].buildDate)
        return cellView
    }
```

I've been stuck with this for about a day and haven't made much progress. I'd appreciate any help

Comment: Only visible rows need views and the views are recycled.

Comment: Please add your code to the question.

Comment: Added. The builds.count is 92, but the viewFor method is only called 12 or 13 times before it stops

Comment: Why are you using `tableColumn!.identifier`? You should assign an identifier to the cell and use it instead. I'm not sure why it even displayed the first 12. From the storyboard, go to the cell and click on it while pressing "ctrl+shift". Select "Table Cell View" and change the identifier from the identity inspector in the right pane. Then, go to your code and change `tableColumn!.identifier` to the cell id.

Comment: I'm just trying to get something up and running. Changing the identifiers and using those makes no difference, the other cells are still not being rendered. Also I am using a XIB not storyboards

Comment: @3li `tableColumn!.identifier` is perfectly fine. The framework assigns implicit identifiers to the columns if none are specified.

Comment: @vadian Oh, I didn't know that. Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

Sweet Jesus, I figured it out. My ruddy `NSWindowController` was being deinitialized straight away so the cells were showing for the visible part of the tableView and then nothing! Keeping a reference to the controller solved this.